# How to reload recyclerview adapterData?

Tags: java, android

[My Codes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ksVXR.jpg)
I am trying to refresh getItemCount and Data in my recyclerview adapter from getData Method. I am working with firebase database. I want to refresh it after ı got datas from firebase.

Comment: Write the code in your post instead of using code screenshot

Answer (score 0):

If you want to  have a set of changes made on your adapter list you can call:

```
 adapter.notifyDataSetChange();
```

After you modify data in your adapter.

In addition if you want to change a specific item  and notify your adapter its better to call:

```
adapter.notifyItemChange(int position);
```

Position is the index of your item in your recycler view or your list.